# load_plugin_textdomain not working

Tags: localization, wordpress

Hey i'm trying to localize a plugin called Donate Plus ( which locallized technicly).

the plugin came with en_CA and de_DE files, i've tried creating a he_IL file without success.
So i've tried with the  de files came with the plugin but didn't work.

I've set the WPLANG in wp-config.php to de_DE yet that dosen't change the code.

this is the setting code :

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'dplus', '/wp-content/plugins/donate-plus' );
```

And i did check that all the string are set to be localized.

Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 13):

I just was  with a similar isue, did you try to rename your files from de_DE.po and de_DE.mo to name-of-plugin-de_DE.mo and name-of-plugin-de_DE.po  (changing name-of-plugin with yours, of course)?

dplus-de_DE.mo and dplus-de_DE.po It must work ;)

Comment: dplus-de_DE.mo and .po work, but it's because it matches the first parameter of the load_plugin_textdomain function. load_plugin_textdomain('**dplus**',....) -> **dplus**-de_DE.mo/po

Comment: yes, you´re right. Is not the name of the plugin, is the textdomain (in the plugins I've tried was the same, but it's righ, it could be different)

Answer (score 3):

load_plugin_textdomain takes three parameters.
In your case it would be something like this (assuming the .po and .mo files are located in a subdir called 'languages')

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'dplus', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the source of [DonatePlus Plugin](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/donate-plus/trunk/donate-plus.php) and I found that the Plugin is doing localization wrongly.

The load_plugin_textdomain() call is made inside the DonatePlus classes constructor. But it should be present inside the 'init' hook. Trying adding the following code (which is at the of the file) inside the *init* function.

```
if( class_exists('DonatePlus') )
    $donateplus = new DonatePlus();
```

Comment: the init hook is a function called SaveSettings, i've tried writing your code in there but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh and tried writing load_plugin_textdomain inside that. still the same. Howeverm my theme locallization dosen't work as well (It's premium so i guess it should)  could this be related?

Comment: Could be related. Can you post the localization code of your theme as well?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I was loading the translation files with the `load_plugin_textdomain` function from within a service class using PSR-4. This meant that the `dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) )` string returned the wrong path.

- The correct path is the relative path `your-plugin/languages` (assuming you are loading the translation files from the `/languages` directory).
- Absolute paths such as `/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages` won't work.

My plugins file structure looks something like this:

```
- my-plugin
    - assets
    - languages
    - services
        - Api
        - Base
            Translation.php
        - ...
        Plugin.php
    - vendor
    - views
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    index.php
    my-plugin.php
    uninstall.php
```

Since my Translation service is placed in the `/services/Base/` directory, this worked for me:

```
$root = plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__, 3));
load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', false, "$root/languages/");
```

Also, I used no action hook at all instead of `init` or `plugins_loaded` and fired the `load_plugin_textdomain` function at the beginning of the plugin, since the hooks don't fire early enough for the admin menu and action links to get translated.

Answer (score -1):

Where are all the .po and .mo files stored? Are they inside the /wp-content/plugins/donate-plus folder itself? If not then change the path or move the files.

Answer (score -1):

Use: 
load_textdomain( TEXT_DOMAIN , WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/'.dirname( plugin_basename( **FILE** ) ) . '/languages/'. get_locale() .'.mo' );